# Conditional Formatting in excel based on another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have an excel worksheet and two columns. I highlight the first column if the value of the cells are less than 0.

Now how can I highlight the second column cells based on the first columns that are highlighted?

See the image below :

[image]

Now I want to make my worksheet like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it as follows (I'll assume that the `4.9755` is in cell `A1`, change as applicable):

1. Select the range of `A1` to `A10`.

   [image]
2. Pull up the conditional formatting dialog and select the option that requires a formula.

   [image]
3. Put the formula `=B1>0` and pick the formatting with font as green.

   [image]
4. Press OK and repeat for the negative values, except using `=B1<0` for the formula and the font as red for the formatting.

   [image]

The number formatting doesn't need conditional formatting, you can simply select the two columns and format as appropriate.

---

If you want to format both columns at the same time, you can select both colums and use the formula `=$B1>0` for green and `=$B1<0` for red:

[image]

Comment: How can I apply to whole column, not one by one. You said "Select the range" and in step 3 you said "Put the formula =B1>0". I want to highlight A1 to A10 cells according to B1 to B10, but this formula highlights A1 to A10 according to B1,

Comment: @PooyaYazdani Did you try it? The conditional formatting adapts to the ranges, so that on A2, the actual formula that applies is `=B2>0`.

Comment: yes I tried it, it doesn't adapt a range to another range! you can simulate this table, I select the first range (A1-A10) an then choose highlight rule, then I select more rules, then Use a formula to determine which cells to format, and then I select second range (B1-B10), but the first range highlights according to first cell of second cell (B1), Is it true? you can simulate this table.

Comment: @PooyaYazdani I didn't make any mention of selecting the second range! Just put the formula I told in my answer in the box and you'll see!

Comment: what do you exactly mean by step 2? which option? where should I put the formula?

Comment: @PooyaYazdani I added pictures.

Comment: Great Appreciates Jerry.

Answer (score 2):

Jerry's answer is correct.  Excel is adaptive, but you must make sure the formula looks exactly like he shows.  If you click on cell B1 the formula will show =$B$1>0 rather than =$B1>0.  The formula cannot contain the $ before the number 1 or it will not be adaptive.  The $ symbol locks the formula, which is helpfull in other situations, but not here.

Comment: Pooya provided a question and not an answer. Did you mean his/her accepted answer instead?

Comment: Thanks - this clarified a confusion I had. I wanted to highlight cells in Column A when cells in the same row of Column E were set, and my formula needed to be `E1<>""` whilst Applies to is set to `=$A:$A`